# How to retrieve students data based on teachers ID

Tags: sql, database, mapping, entity-relationship

According to a simple scenario ER diagram as follows.

[image]

Based on that, I developed a database mapping as follows.

[image]

In there, orange color columns shows the primary key of the tables and yellow color columns shows foreign key of the tables. Is this mapping correct? Now my problem is I need to retrieve students data who learned from some teacher, which means need to retrieve some teacher's sudents who learned from his/her.

Comment: Show us what you have tried till now?

Comment: @PSK sir I'm new to databases, I don't have an idea to write join query to do this.please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn about how to join tables using different types of available JOINs.

For your scenario , try like following, it will give you Student and the Teacher mapping.

```
select s.*
tbl_student s
inner join tbl_Course_Subjects tcs on s.Course_Id= tcs.Course_Id
inner join tbl_Subjects_Teacher tst on tst.SubjectId=tcs.Subject_Id
inner join tbl_Teacher t on t.Teacher_Id=tst.Teacher_Id
where t.Teacher_Id = @SomeTeacherId
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir :) can you please explain is this mapping is correct?  Should I need to normalize this?

Comment: As per the ERD, the design looks fine to me.